# significance of PCA with EWMA

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, pca, moving-average, random-matrix

I am evaluating a PCA on a set of 45 financial time series where EWMA (exponentially weighted moving averages) has been applied.

A small intro. An EWMA statistic has a form
$$
\hat{y}_t = \sum_s \lambda^s y(x_{t-s}) \big/\sum_s \lambda^s
$$
You can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) for more description.

First, I compute the EWMA mean and standard deviation, and I standardize the time series, which I will call $r_t$. The $\lambda$ I use is 0.95, and is obtained (as typically done) by minimizing the error

$$
\sum_i ((r^i_{t+1} - \mu^i_t(\lambda))^2 - \sigma_t^{i,2}(\lambda))^2
$$

After this I compute the covariance matrix of $\{r_t^i\}_i$, again using EWMA. Once I'm there, I want to compute a PCA, to understand a bit more what is going on. Now, I understand that the [Marchenko-Pastur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) theorem is typically used to select the statistically significant eigenvalues. My question is, what is the number of data that we have to assume in the context of that theorem?

I would naively use $\lambda^{-1}$ (or some more sophisticated similar calculation) as the number of data points in each time series. The problem with that is that the limit of the distribution under the null hypothesis is 56.8, which is higher than the highest eigenvalue (this situation repeats at all times).

The obvious conclusion would be that those eigenvalues are not significant. However, if the correlation between the first eigenvectors at different times is quite high (say > 0.9). This would be an indication that they actually represent some long-term feature in the data. The alternative conclusion is that my estimation for the number of data in the time series is incorrect. But then, how much should it be?

Answer (score 1):

> I would naively use $\lambda^{-1}$ (or some more sophisticated similar calculation) as the number of data points

With $\lambda^{-1} = 1/0.95 \approx 1.05$ you are using approximately 1.05 datapoints? That is extremely low.

If you compute $$\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{45}{1.05}} \right)^2 \approx 56.8$$ then you are extremely underestimating the number of datapoints.

---

You could determine a cut-off $\lambda$ by simulations.

Repeatedly generate $45$ columns with data. Perform the EWMA smoothening and then compute the correlation matrix and eigenvalues. Then see the distribution of those eigenvalues and whether the smoothening has a large effect on te effective number of datapoints.

Below is an example where we have 45 columns of 200 points and we changed the $\lambda$ variable

The red curve that we added follows the relation

$$\lambda_+ = \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{m}{n(1-\lambda)}} \right)^2$$

So it seems like the moving average reduces the effective number of points approximately by a factor $1-\lambda$.

[image: simulation]

```
sim = function(n = 100, m = 45, q = 0.95) {
  ### generate data
  x = matrix(rnorm(m*n),n)
  y = x*0
  
  ### compute moving average
  filt = q^c(0:(n-1))
  for (i in 1:m) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
      y[j,i] = sum(filt[j:1]*x[1:j,i])/sum(filt[j:1])
    }
  }
  
  ### standardize
  mu = rep(1,n) %*% t(apply(y,2,mean))
  sig = rep(1,n) %*% t(apply(y,2,var)^0.5)
  y = (y - mu)/sig
  
  mu = rep(1,n) %*% t(apply(x,2,mean))
  sig = rep(1,n) %*% t(apply(x,2,var)^0.5)
  x = (x - mu)/sig
  
  ### compute eigenvalues
  
  ev_x = eigen(t(x) %*% x/n)
  ev_y = eigen(t(y) %*% y/n)
  
  return(list(x=max(ev_x$values),y = max(ev_y$values)))
}

set.seed(1)
m = 45
n = 200
q = seq(0,1,0.005)

values = sapply(q, FUN = function(qs) sim(n=n, q = qs))
boundary = (1+sqrt(m/n))^2

plot(c(0,1),boundary*c(1,1), type = "l", lty = 2,
     ylim = c(0,max(as.numeric(values))),
     xlab = expression(lambda),
     ylab = "sampled eigenvalue maximum")
points(q,as.numeric(values[2,]),
       pch = 21, col = 1, bg = 0, cex = 0.7)

lines(q, (1+sqrt( m/(n*(1-q)) ))^2, col = 2)
```

Comment: why is underestimating? i.e. wrt what? At each time only the 6% of the previous time is taken into account. Thanks for the advice of trying with synthetic data, I will try

Comment: @Chuse an estimate of 1.05 for the number of points is extremely low. Also, you would expect that somehow the number of data points should be involved and not just the parameter $\lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: If I pick $\lambda\sim0.95$ then the data is practically the same as taking one single time (or row), i.e. $n=1$. So, I know it's a very low estimate, but to me it makes sense because the values of the correlation matrix are practically the same as having $n=1$.

Comment: The simulations I did suggest against my intuition, i.e. a higher $\lambda$ is equivalent to a higher $n$. I'm really confused

Comment: thanks, I reached to a very similar conclusion, but I think that $n$ doesn't enter into the formula, because it's irrelevant how large the table is. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

My naive solution was wrong. An "equivalent" number of rows $n*$ can be calculated as $$
\sum_{s\ge 0} \lambda^s = \frac1{1-\lambda}
$$

Using this, $n^*(\lambda=0.95)=20$, which is a more reasonable estimate. With it, the Marchenko-Pastur limit is 6.25, a result supported by simulations.

In general, the limit should be
$$
\lambda_+ = \left(1 + \sqrt{m(1-\lambda)}\right)^2
$$

Comment: Do you also include the actual number of rows in the computation of the equivalent number of rows? The limit changes when you have a different amount of rows $n$ while keeping the columns $m$ and $\lambda$ the same.

Comment: I used much larger tables (to 10k rows) and the largest eigenvalue is still around 6

Comment: Is that for simulated data or for data where you might get larger eigenvalues because the null hypothesis is not true?

Comment: You happened to have this value of 6.25 by chance. The formula does not make sense. Try it out with some simulations varying the column length $n$ or varying the parameter $\lambda$. Something that clearly shows that your formula is wrong is when you consider $\lambda \to 0$. In that case your $\lambda_+$ approaches $(1+\sqrt{m})^2$ and is independent of $n$ which makes little sense. The smaller that $\lambda$ is, the more you will expect the value to approximate $(1+\sqrt{m/n})^2$ and you would expect a *decrease* of $\lambda_+$ (see my simulation where you get this decrease).

Comment: I think that in the case $\lambda\rightarrow0$, that is exactly when you have only the last point in the time series, and therefore $n^*=1$. The case in which $n^*= n$ is when $\lambda=1$. In the formula that doesn't work because it is assumed that the time series is kind of infinite. But is a limiting case, and for any practical application ($\lambda\sim0.99$ or below), it's ok. Do you agree?

Comment: In the case of $\lambda \to 0$ then $$\hat{y}_t = \sum_s \lambda^s x_{t-s} \big/\sum_s \lambda^s \to \sum_s I(s=0) x_{t-s} \big/\sum_s I(s=0)  = x_t$$ $\lambda^s\big/\sum_s \lambda^s \to I(s=0)$ approaches the indicator function for $\lambda \to 0$ and is equal to $1$ when $s=0$ and equal to $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: *"you have only the last point in the time series"* You don't just have one time point right? We are using $\hat{y}_1, \hat{y}_2, \hat{y}_3, \dots, \hat{y}_n$ or not? (And indeed, for each of these $\hat{y}_i$ they relate only to the last time point $y_i$, but you have many different $i$ of them)

Comment: with "you have only the last point" I meant that $\hat{y}_t=x_t$. But is also the case that the correlation matrix will be just the covariance of data at time $t$, not before, and therefore $n^*=1$.

Comment: You are not computing a correlation matrix for an n by m matrix?